# PHP & MySQL Wildcards? or so I think

Tags: php, mysql, wildcard

I am not sure if this even a wildcard or how to even construct this code. Basically what I am trying to achieve is selecting from `user_ranks` table, each row has a unique id and in the `users` table, there's a column called `ranks` and it would have each `user_rank` id separated by `|` characters.

So for example, in `users` table, I have the `rank` of `|2|4|14|13|` - each ID in there is the `id` in `user_ranks`.

**Here's what I've got so far which is obviously so wrong.**

```
$usersquery = $db->query("SELECT rank FROM users WHERE username = '" . $username ."'");

while ($users = $usersquery->fetch_assoc()) {
    $ranksquery = $db->query(
        "SELECT * FROM user_ranks WHERE id LIKE '%[" . $users['rank'] . "]%'"
    );
    while ($ranks = $ranksquery->fetch_assoc()) {
        return $ranks['id'];            
    }
}
```

If you need any extra information, please let me know, it was a bit hard to explain this, thank you so much for any help I can get!

Comment: Give an example of the data you want returned. For example, so you want each element in the string assigned to a separate var?

Comment: I want it to return the id from `users_ranks` for each id that is used in `ranks` in the `users` table.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/4tw1kt
http://prntscr.com/4tw1s0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PHP's `explode` and `trim` to get the separate IDs from `$users['rank']`:

```
$rank_ids = explode('|', trim($users['rank'], '|'));
```

Then use this SQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_ranks WHERE id IN (" . implode(", ", $rank_ids) . ")";
```

Comment: This only gets the first id from the rank and breaks the rest of the page

Comment: trim cleans the first and last |. Then explode splits the string in an array of IDs, based on the | separation character. Do a var_dump($users['rank'], $rank_ids) after the $rank_ids = explode(..) line to see what you got. Then if you are sure it looks good, implode joins the given array into a string, separated with the ", " character. This makes the IN (...) set that you need in your SQL.

Comment: So your example of "|2|4|14|13|" becomes an array of the values 2, 4, 14, 13. Imploding this creates the string "2, 4, 14, 13", and then your SQL would be "SELECT * FROM user_ranks WHERE id IN (2, 4, 14, 13)", which should get you the user ranks you need. Try it in your MySQL console or phpmyadmin.

Comment: Hi, the var_dump returned this
`string(11) "|2|4|14|13|" array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "4" [2]=> string(2) "14" [3]=> string(2) "13" }`

Comment: Looks good to me. When you imploded that $rank_ids array into the SQL, what does var_dump($sql) tell you? Does it look like the SQL I posted in the earlier comment? And did you try it in your MySQL client?

Comment: Yeah I echo'd it and it returned as you said it would, I also tried it in navicat and it selected the right ranks. Probably just an error in my code now. Thank you so much for your help :)